# Possible valid queries for simple GraphQL schema

Tags: graphql, schema

I wanted to confirm if I'm understanding correctly GraphQL schema. With the following (very static I suppose?) simple schema:

```
type User {
  login: String
  password: String
}

type System {
  users: [User!]!
}
```

there are only 3 possible valid queries:

```
query SimpleQuery1 {
      system {
        users {
          login
          password
        }
      }
    }
```

```
query SimpleQuery2 {
      system {
        users {
          login
        }
      }
    }
```

```
query SimpleQuery3 {
      system {
        users {
          password
        }
      }
    }
```

And that's it, no other possible queries?

Comment: This may be a bit pedantic, but since we don't know why you're asking this, we don't know what standard to use to distinguish between different GraphQL documents and say "this is one query and this is a different query". I could think of any number of additional documents you *could* write based on that schema that would result in different ASTs, but might generate the same response. I guess my question is, are you only concerned about possible [selection sets](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Selection-Sets)?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I think my answer covered most variants of "valid queries" that could be made against the above schema. And yes, you have to provide some kind of type (conventionally named `Query`) as the root query type. This serves as an entry point to your schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have any number of [ignored tokens](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Source-Text.Ignored-Tokens) like spaces, line breaks and commas that would technically result in different documents.

Outside of changing your operation name (i.e. `SimpleQuery2`), you could also utilize [query shorthand](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Language.Operations):

```
{
  system {
    users {
      login
    }
  }
}
```

The order of the fields in the response depends on their order in the request, so these two queries would yield different responses (insofar as ordering of keys is concerned):

```
query {
  system {
    users {
      login
      password
    }
  }
}

query {
  system {
    users {
      password
      login
    }
  }
}
```

You could have duplicate fields, although the duplicates would be eliminated in the actual response:

```
query {
  system {
    users {
      login
      login
      login
    }
  }
}
```

But you could also utilize [aliases](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Field-Alias) to keep the duplicate fields:

```
query {
  system {
    users {
      login1: login
      login2: login
      login3: login
    }
  }
}
```

Your query could utilize one or more [fragments](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Validation.Fragments):

```
query {
  system {
    users {
      ...on UserFields
    }
  }
}

fragment UserFields on User {
  login
}
```

And while it's largely pointless unless you're dealing with abstract types, you could also use inline fragments:

```
query {
  system {
    users {
      ...on User {
        login
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Lastly, you could utilize [`@skip`](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec--skip) or [`@include`](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec--include) directives to vary which fields are actually resolves. It's possible to skip all the fields in a selection set, resulting in an empty object being returned.

```
query($someCondition: Boolean!, $someOtherCondition: Boolean) {
  system {
    users {
      login @skip(if: $someCondition)
      password @include(if: $someOtherCondition)
    }
  }
}
```

Whether you consider these *different* queries depends on the context. With the exception of the alias example and the directives example, all of these would result in the same response as one of your three original queries. However, all of these examples are semantically different and would end up getting parsed into a different looking AST.

EDIT: GraphQL also supports [introspection](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Introspection) so the following types of queries will also be "valid" provided introspection is enabled on the server:

```
{
  __type(name: "User") {
    name
    fields {
      name
      type {
        name
      }
    }
  }
}

{
  __schema {
    queryType {
      name
      fields {
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for elaborate answer, it essentially answers my question. So just to confirm: providing above schema, there is no option to ask for only 10 first users, because such query is not defined in the schema, am I correct?

Comment: Correct, there is no built-in filtering, slicing, pagination, etc. in GraphQL. You have to add those arguments to the appropriate fields yourself, and then make sure your resolver logic does something with them.